# How I can get a location of response headers for this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Could please someone tell me, how can I get a location of response headers for the following respones?

```
http = Net::HTTP.new "s3.amazonaws.com"
response = http.request_head(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

Net::HTTP response headers are accessible using the element selection operator ([]) on the response object itself:

```
response['Authorization']
```